# How can I react to a message with a pub/sub bot

Tags: google-hangouts

I have created a Card with a button and a onClick action that successfully sends a message to my client with type "CARD_CLICKED".
When I try to respond to this message with either a type "NEW_MESSAGE" or "UPDATE_MESSAGE" message, this is displayed as a new message, while the API tries for three times to send that CARD_CLICKED event to my bot until it gives up with the visual error: "Unable to contact [bot]. Try again later."

I guess this is similar to

- [Interactive button doesn't work properly when using pub/sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49785504/interactive-button-doesnt-work-properly-when-using-pub-sub)
- [Interactive cards hangout chat Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51631989/interactive-cards-hangout-chat-api)

but I am using a golang client and the answer to these questions didn't help me...

My code to respond to the "CARD_CLICKED" message:

```
func handleClick(message *chat.DeprecatedEvent) *chat.Message {
    log.Debugf("User %s instructed me to execute %s", message.User.DisplayName, message.Action.ActionMethodName)

    response := &chat.Message{
        ActionResponse: &chat.ActionResponse{Type: "UPDATE_MESSAGE"},
        Thread:         &chat.Thread{Name: message.Message.Thread.Name},
        Space:          &chat.Space{Name: message.Message.Space.Name, Type: message.Message.Space.Type},
        Text:           "CARD CLICKED!",
    }
    return response
}
```

My code is based on this project: https://github.com/jforman/hangbot

Answer (score 1):

Found out what the main issue was... I was calling the .Create() function - which created a new message and thus - even though the Action Response was set correctly - this was not interpreted as a response to the click event:
https://github.com/jforman/hangbot/blob/master/hangbot.go#L79

After I switched to calling .Update() - Chat would not display the "Unable to contact" message about my bot any more.

What remains is that the click event is *still* sent to me three times, but I'm filtering events now based on the eventTime, which works ok for now.

Comment: what do you mean by calling the .create() function? where do you call that? I just send back the new card to the same api that creates a new message: https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/[...]/messages?[...]

Comment: Yes - but since I was using the .create() function, the API didn't interpret it as a _response_ to the click, but as a completely new message
My solution is available here:
https://github.com/mulbc/botanist/blob/master/hangouts.go#L169