# Which event(s) to use in place of Google Chat's "DeprecatedEvent"

Tags: go, google-hangouts

I have several questions related to `google.golang.org/api/chat/v1`.

1. It seems the only available `Event` object is [`DeprecatedEvent`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/chat/v1#DeprecatedEvent). So, what is the non-deprecated one to use?
2. If `DeprecatedEvent` is indeed the intended one to use, inside the `DeprecatedEvent` object, there's a `User *User` field. However, it seems that the [`User`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/chat/v1#User) object is different from what I actually got from the responses.

For example:

```
{
  'eventTime': '2019-08-27T06:50:12.391141Z',
  'user': {
    'name': 'users/112...',
    'email': 'iskandar.setiadi@...',
    'avatarUrl': 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAu...',
    'displayName': 'Iskandar Setiadi',
    'type': 'HUMAN'
  },
  'type': 'ADDED_TO_SPACE',
  'space': {
    'name': 'spaces/7ag...',
    'type': 'DM'
  }
}
```

In the API, `User` object only contains `displayName`, `name`, and `type`. It seems that `email` and `avatarUrl` are not there. Is v1 outdated or is there any alternatives that I don't know?

Comment: Should https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557076/how-can-i-react-to-a-message-with-a-pub-sub-bot be linked here?